# Web service method called once, but executed multiple times

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm developing a web service in Java EE 6, with only one method called E1CreateAccount.

It happens that for each call I do to the method, the execution of the method fires multiple times (at least 2 times). The executions are consecutive, so the next start when the previous ends.

The code of the method is the following:

```
@WebMethod
public Object E1CreateAccount(@WebParam(name = "arg0") InboundAccountF56101IB newAccount) {
    Object ret = "KO";
    MyAction action = MyAction.CREATE;
    MyLogger.getLogger().info("Integration WebService called to Create new Account in E1, name " +
            newAccount.getCRMAccountName());
    E1AccountClientThread runner = new E1AccountClientThread();
    runner.initialize(newAccount, action);
    Thread thread = new Thread(runner);
    MyLogger.getLogger().info(thread.getId() + ": Created thread to " + action.name() +
            " Account. Account Name: " + newAccount.getCRMAccountName() + "...");
    try {
        MyLogger.getLogger().info(thread.getId() +
                ": Starting thread to call E1 Account web service, Action: " +
                action.name());
        thread.start();
        ret = "OK";
    } catch(Exception e) {
        String str = "Exception calling the thread delegate to call E1 Account web service (Action " +
                action.name() + ". Message: " + e.getMessage().toString();
        MyLogger.getLogger().severe(str);
        ret="KO " + str;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It receive the call, it logs the fact that the service has been called, and then create a separated thread which will do the task. Then it always return the string "OK".

The method works well, the only problem is the multiple execution, which is undesired for the software purposes.

This is what I see from the logs:

```
Jul 06, 2015 3:17:57 PM integration.services.e1.account.E1AccountService E1CreateAccount
INFO: Integration WebService called to Create new Account in E1, name THIS_IS_THE_COMPANY_NAME
Jul 06, 2015 3:17:57 PM integration.services.e1.account.E1AccountService E1CreateAccount
INFO: 1026: Created thread to CREATE Account. Account Name: THIS_IS_THE_COMPANY_NAME...
Jul 06, 2015 3:17:57 PM integration.services.e1.account.E1AccountService E1CreateAccount
INFO: 1026: Starting thread to call E1 Account web service, Action: CREATE
[...]
Jul 06, 2015 3:18:00 PM integration.services.e1.account.E1AccountService E1CreateAccount
INFO: Integration WebService called to Create new Account in E1, name THIS_IS_THE_COMPANY_NAME
Jul 06, 2015 3:18:00 PM integration.services.e1.account.E1AccountService E1CreateAccount
INFO: 1027: Created thread to CREATE Account. Account Name: THIS_IS_THE_COMPANY_NAME...
Jul 06, 2015 3:18:00 PM integration.services.e1.account.E1AccountService E1CreateAccount
INFO: 1027: Starting thread to call E1 Account web service, Action: CREATE
[...]
```

(I substituted with [...] the logs related to what the threads actually do because I think it is not relevant)

The web service has been deployed on WebLogic 12.1.3, and I used the ide JDeveloper 12.1.3